# What is inside Callback queue (debugger)?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how is it possible to know the content of the callback queue.
For example, if you consider the following Javascript code :

```
<script>
    console.clear();   
    setTimeout( function () {console.log("Hello ")},5000);      
    console.log("What is inside Callback Queue ? ");        
</script>
```

Is there a mean to print the content of the callback queue to the console ?
If not possible in such that way, is it possible with a debugger by adding a break point to the line `console.log("What is inside ...?");` (I tried with Firefox debugger but I did not manage to do it)
Or another solution ?
Thanks for answer.

Comment: You don't have access to it. That's true for both the things you might be referring to - the `setTimeout` will generally add a *timer* that will eventually add something to the *event queue*. I'm not sure what you mean by "callback queue" but you can't directly see either of the two things involved here.

Comment: @vlaz Not sure about that, the performance tab might give some insights.

Comment: @JonasWilms I was thinking of direct programmatic access - it's what OP seems to be after with this code.

Comment: @VLAZ. Concerning your remark about callback queue, I was refering to the first figure in the following link : https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-nodejs-development/9781788395540/dfdddbf7-1521-4c8e-af8e-e47900ae5002.xhtml

Comment: @VLAZ Any solution is welcome. I could use anything else than direct programmatic access.

Comment: @JonasWilms. Thanks. You could move your comment to answer. I did not use this tab yet. I filter only function calls and it is perfect.

Comment: How about you do that? I'm currently afk, and I haven't worked with that tab for a while. You seem to already have it working, so you could share that knowledge with future visitors :)

Comment: @JonasWilms. I post an answer. Do not hesitate to edit it because I have just discovered this tool.

Answer (score 1):

The performance tab of the browser's developer tools contains all the informations needed. Do the following:

1. Filter markers : function call (only to avoid a lot of
   informations)
2. Start Recording
3. Reload (CTRL + R)
4. Stop Recording (With my example, when Hello is printed to the console)

In the waterfall, Click on the mark that appears after 5000ms (with my example) and useful informations are displayed in the right pane.

Answer (score -1):

While I'm not sure what your final goal is, you can wrap the function you're calling with the following `wrapper` function, which prints to the log whenever a function is being enqueued:

```js
function wrapper(func) {
  console.log(`'${func.name}' was enqueued`);
  return func;
}

function foo() {
  console.log('Hello')
}

setTimeout(wrapper(foo), 5000);
```

You can use a similar mechanism to maintain an array that'll contain all the functions that are currently waiting.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it is to understand a code that I have not written (c3.js and d3.js libraries)

Comment: I'm not sure what "queue" you (and the OP) are talking about here ... Timers don't necessarily end up in a queue when you start them.

Comment: @JonasWilms The event loop

Comment: Well then your log is totally useless. `setTimeout(wrapper(foo), Infinity)`

Comment: What are you trying to prove with this example? The OP asked how to view the functions that are waiting execution, with a very specific definition. Your example is clearly not within the boundaries of it.